# SQL query to update table property from a relation's property of the said table

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to update the `ACCOUNT_GROUP` column in a table `BILL_INFO_DETAIL` from a similar column in table `SERVICE_INFO` that has a foreign key to `BILL_INFO_DETAIL`. Each `BILL_INFO_DETAIL` can have one `SERVICE_INFO`.

I tried this code, but it didn't select the proper `SERVICE_INFO` as the `WHERE` clause didn't work as I intended:

```
UPDATE BILL_INFO_DETAIL
SET ACCOUNT_CODE = (SELECT TOP (1) si.ACCOUNT_CODE
                    FROM SERVICE_INFO si
                    WHERE si.SERVICE_CODE = SERVICE_CODE);
```

All items in `BILL_INFO_DETAIL`'s `ACCOUNT_CODE` got set to the first `ACCOUNT_CODE` of `SERVICE_INFO`

Seems this is not that straight forward. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After digging further, I found out how to have Inner Join in Update queries from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293347/481656

I modified my query likewise:

```
UPDATE b
SET b.ACCOUNT_CODE = s.ACCOUNT_CODE
FROM BILL_INFO_DETAIL b
INNER JOIN SERVICE_INFO s ON b.SERVICE_CODE = s.SERVICE_CODE
```

It worked out nicely.

Rubber Duck.